# A matrix with as rows all the elements in $\{0,1\}^7$ of odd weight, parity check matrix?

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

The only information on the matrix $H$ is that its rows are all the elements in $K^7$ ($K=\{0,1\}$) of odd weight (odd amount of ones). If I count them, there are 7 elements of weight 1, there are $7C3=35$ of weight 3, $7C5=21$ of weight 5 and 1 of weight 7. All in all, $64$ elements in $K^7$ of odd weight. Now the matrix $H$ is a $64\times7$ matrix.

How to show that $H$ is a parity-check matrix for some (binary) linear code $C$? The definition of a parity check matrix states it has to be $n\times(n-k)$, but since $n=7$ (codes in $K^7$ are of length $7$), this can not be true. With this I don't even know how to get the size of the code $C$ of which $H$ is the parity check matrix.

Maybe the length of the code $C$ is actually 64?

Comment: Are there not $\binom{7}{1} = 7$ elements of weight 1?

Comment: In any case, yes: the length of the code words in $C$ is (in this convention for $H$) indeed the number of rows of $H$, not columns.

Comment: @prets yes you're right, typo. Ok, that clears it up. So now I have a 64x7 parity check matrix, so the linear code is $(n,k,d)=(64,57,d)$ where I think $d(C)=4$ since every set of 3 rows from $H$ is lin indep, but it's easy to find 4 rows that are lin dep.

Comment: One can get the number of odd weight elements more quickly by noting that every odd-parity element is the bitswap of an even weight element.